# Parallel of Task.Run that set values of an array

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

I'm trying to figuring out how this code behave not as my expectation. I have a piece of code that when run I expect it would set each element of the array with an unpredictable value but it set all element with a same value. e.g expectation `[1, 32, 0, 1, 32, 3125, ...]` but it yield `[32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32]` instead. Why?

Here is the code:

```
int l = 1000000;
var mc = new int[10];
var rand = new Random();
var tasks = new Task[l];
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    tasks[i] = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var r = i % 10;
        mc[0] = r * r * r * r * r; // just to make it run longer
        mc[1] = r * r * r * r * r;
        mc[2] = r * r * r * r * r;
        mc[3] = r * r * r * r * r;
        mc[4] = r * r * r * r * r;
        mc[5] = r * r * r * r * r;
        mc[6] = r * r * r * r * r;
        mc[7] = r * r * r * r * r;
        mc[8] = r * r * r * r * r;
        mc[9] = r * r * r * r * r;
    });

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

**Edit1**
In my knowledge, if each task runs in parallel, some thread will try to modify the array simultaneously, means if thread 0 modifies to mc[5], another thread 1 would attempt to modify mc[0], then mc[0] and mc[5] may have difference number.

Comment: Why would you expect any random behaviour when you create a `Random` object and then ignore it throughout the rest of your code?

Comment: You've set all the mc array values to be the same, I havent bothered to check why 32, but, I would expect them all to result in the same number.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it safe to remove `Random` from my example code.

Comment: @BugFinder yes, I don't understand why it results in the same number.

Comment: because `mc[n]=r*r*r*r*r` ... all of them, r never changes, so it will always be the same result.

Comment: @BugFinder please take a look at my edit1

Comment: Not necessarily... and there in lies the answer.. the task you're running is really quick, theres a really good chance because you spawn them one after the other, that they will have completed... you're relying on freaks of nature to provide a randomness, rather than relying on actual randomness

Comment: I'm not trying to provide some randomness, I want to make sure if there is any chance that an array will be modify this way if I have a computation that takes long enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
int l = 1000000;
var mc = new int[10000];
var rand = new Random();
var tasks = new Task[l];
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
{
    var i2 = i;
    tasks[i2] = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var r = i2 % 100;
        for (var x = 0; x < 10000; x ++)
        {
            mc[x] = r * r * r * r * r;
        }
    });
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

More often than not, when I output `mc.Distinct()`, I get this kind of result:

```
919965907 
17210368
```

The two things that I did was to capture `i` locally within the loop using `i2` and I extended `mc` to have 10,000 elements.

Once I even got 7 different values.

Do keep in mind that you're modifying values simultaneously without any locking so you could get all sorts of race conditions causes unexpected values. This is not good code for anything other than fun.

Comment: That 2 things make it works. I use this to test my Object Pooling api, I want to make sure no object is allocated twice. Great answer!